# check lastcolumn used for each row

Tags: vba, excel

Each row can have different last used column.I want to check column for each row which is last column. How I can do that?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        LastCol = 1
    Else
        LastCol = rng.Column
    End If
    Debug.Print LastCol
End Sub
```

This code is for finding last column(common for all rows). But I want to check different last used column for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways, here is one demo using the following data.  It also gives you one method for finding the last row using column A.  You may need to write something to convert column number to column letter.

Note also that you can specify the row/col being tested, by using either a variable e.g. `rw` as in `Cells(rw, Columns.Count)` or a constant e.g. `"A"` as in `Cells(Rows.Count, "A")`.

Finally, especially if you are using multiple worksheets, you may also need to take care to specify the worksheet on which the data you are using resides, as in `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.  In my example, and unless otherwise 'qualified' in this way, the data on the `ActiveSheet` will be used.  So be sure to select the sheet containing your data before running this code example.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub lastCol()
Dim lCol As Long, rw As Long
    For rw = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        MsgBox "For row " & rw & ", last column is " & lCol
    Next rw
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub lrow()
Dim lCol As Long, rw As Long
    For rw = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If Cells(rw, lCol).Value = "rajani" Then
                MsgBox "Row " & rw & ", last column " & lCol & " contains rajani"
            End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Also i want to check whether the last column contain specific data how can i do that??

Comment: i want to check whether text entered in last column is "rajani" or not

Comment: `If Cells(rw,lCol) = "rajani" then `